# Changes rods for linear rails

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I would like to know if it is possible to change the rollers for linear rails, just replacing or some calculation should be done and take some precautions.

In my case,  I have a Core XY DIY printer.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I was reading about need to migrate of 8 Bits to 32 Bits, because for get better resolution, results and should be update more things, like add autolevel, etc.

Comment: Pedro, please post the 8/32-bit question in a separate question. You will receive far better answers for both your questions that way.

Comment: When i say about 8/32 Bits, was just for know the recommendations than i read, It would be more profitable to have a card that works at 32 than one of 8, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen mods for the Hypercube (and Hypercube Evolution) using linear rails (e.g. [this mod](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2839395)), so yes that is possible. You need to redesign a few parts and make sure you have the correct length, but that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thankas for your answer. Although in the description of the model it says that it is for a 300x300x300 model, and in my case I have one of 200x200x200. How do you recalculate for the desired size?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales First design new idler X-Y mounts and Y mounts, from there you can calculate how long the linear rails need to be. If you buy the rails larger than needed (e.g. outer size of the cube, or between the aluminium profiles), you can cut them to size later.